# changes and modified files larger doing a PR from a Fork

Tags: git

At our work we have a policy where the final code is in master in a repo, and everyone has to make a fork and then make a PR to push the changes.

I'm using [syncing-a-fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) for my workflow, doing all my changes locally in master and then doing the PR. This was OK until I started creating branches locally, basically my flow with a branch was like this:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
git checkout -b feature
```

With that my intent was get all the latest changes from master, then I created a new Branch and start to commit locally my changes. After I finished with my feature I tried to get all the commits made to master so i did this:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
git push master
git checkout my-branch
git merge master
```

And then push my changes to github and from there create the PR, the problem with this is that the PR marks as "modified files" my changes and all the changes from the commits, so instead of 20 modified files I see something like 200.

What is the correct flow to follow in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to "rebase" your changes on top of the latest commit in `master`:

```
git checkout my-branch
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

That is, the commits you made in your branch will appear as if they had been made on top of what's currently in `master`.  If there are any conflicts between your branch and `master`, `git rebase` will prompt you to resolve them before proceeding.

Alternatively, if the changes that have been made to `master` while you were working on your branch are small, you can just create a PR from your branch without merging/rebasing.

---

The "syncing a fork" workflow is suitable when you have two branches, slightly different from each other, that you want to keep up-to-date over a longer period of time.  That doesn't apply in this case: you create a feature branch, open a PR, PR gets merged, and then you delete the feature branch.